# SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I checked the parameters, and fields, nothing is mispelled,But I still get that error..

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("SELECT u.Name,t.ThreadTitle,t.Date, t.Views,t.Replies,p.Theme,p.Topics,t.PageNumber");
    sb.Append("FROM Users AS u");
    sb.Append("INNER JOIN Threads AS t ON u.UserID=t.UserID");
    sb.Append("INNER JOIN Topics AS p ON p.TopicID=t.TopicID");
    sb.Append("WHERE u.UserID=@UserID");
    sb.Append("ORDER BY t.Date");
```

Another question will ORDER by date work.. that field is of type TimeDate as much as I remember.

Comment: Perhaps ypu need to add spaces? For example: t.PageNumber and FROM will be one word because they are appended together without space...?

Comment: 1. Maybe you should just use AppendLine() method? 2. Order by date should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SELECT u.Name,t.ThreadTitle,t.Date, t.Views,t.Replies,p.Theme,p.Topics,t.PageNumber");
sb.Append(" FROM Users AS u");
sb.Append(" INNER JOIN Threads AS t ON u.UserID=t.UserID");
sb.Append(" INNER JOIN Topics AS p ON p.TopicID=t.TopicID");
sb.Append(" WHERE u.UserID=@UserID");
sb.Append(" ORDER BY t.Date");
```

And Yes, orderby should work.

Comment: Thanks it did. i have another problem. How do you convert a parameter from the reader to an int.. Views = int.Parse(dr["Views"].ToString()); (dr is SQLDataReader). it gives me input string was not in the correct format

Comment: @NewOrder, what's the data type of Views column? If it is int then use int Views = dr.GetInt32(3);

Answer (score 3):

You have no space between "Users AS u" and "INNER JOIN". Add spaces:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SELECT u.Name,t.ThreadTitle,t.Date, t.Views,t.Replies,p.Theme,p.Topics,t.PageNumber ");
sb.Append("FROM Users AS u ");
sb.Append("INNER JOIN Threads AS t ON u.UserID=t.UserID ");
sb.Append("INNER JOIN Topics AS p ON p.TopicID=t.TopicID ");
sb.Append("WHERE u.UserID=@UserID ");
sb.Append("ORDER BY t.Date");
```

Alternatively, use line breaks by invoking [`AppendLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx) instead of `Append`.

Even better, since this is all just one long string, use a verbatim string:

```
var sql = @"
SELECT u.Name,t.ThreadTitle,t.Date, t.Views,t.Replies,p.Theme,p.Topics,t.PageNumber
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Threads AS t ON u.UserID=t.UserID
INNER JOIN Topics AS p ON p.TopicID=t.TopicID
WHERE u.UserID=@UserID
ORDER BY t.Date";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending everything to a single line. Add space or use [AppendLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx) instead of Append.